# Laravel Showing Index Of / after uploading the site but works fine on localhost

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-5

I am trying to upload a basic site made under Laravel FW. I uploaded the site outside the `public_html` folder in a folder called **laraveltest**. I moved the public folder from here to the `public_html` folder.  In this folder I have the `index.php` file and I changed two lines to :-

---

inside (**public_html**/**public**/*index.php*)

```
require __DIR__.'/../laraveltest/vendor/autoload.php';
$app = require_once __DIR__.'/../laraveltest/bootstrap/app.php';
```

---

I also changed my .env files that located outside public_html folder, and there a is a folder in the root called laraveltest. I changed the username/ database name and also the password.

When i load the site now, i used to get the page says Index Of / .

---

After doing some research and youTube videos, I then added a .htaccess file inside the (**public_html)** folder.

.htaccess

```
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
    <IfModule mod_negotiation.c>
        Options -MultiViews -Indexes
    </IfModule>

    RewriteEngine On

    # Handle Authorization Header
    RewriteCond %{HTTP:Authorization} .
    RewriteRule .* - [E=HTTP_AUTHORIZATION:%{HTTP:Authorization}]

    # Redirect Trailing Slashes If Not A Folder...
    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} (.+)/$
    RewriteRule ^ %1 [L,R=301]

    # Handle Front Controller...
    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
    RewriteRule ^ public/index.php [L]
</IfModule>
```

Now when I reload the page, I get an error

> This page isn’t working ***mylivewebsite.com***  is currently unable to handle
>   this request. HTTP ERROR 500

I have also checked the permission and it is all set to  `0777` as well.

Please let me know how can I make my website run correctly.

Comment: Pretty sure you should not be modifying index.php. Why not place whole project in public folder together with .htaccess file? Also check that .htaccess is enabled in Apache.

Comment: @cen I first installed the project under public_html and it didnt work at all. So i did some research and watched few youTube videos and I followed one of them. but it didnt work either ways

Comment: Uploading your project to public root, adding .htaccess and running composer should be all you need to do. If you have multiple sites then you probably want to use virtual hosts aswell. Google returns plenty of tutorials for "laravel apache deployment", check them out. What is your working local setup?

Comment: Ok, I will upload  fresh file again inside public_html folder. I am uploading the zip file and extract it through cPanel. And in case if i had to edit anything, I right click the file and edit it. My PHP version is 7.1, how can I run the composer on the cPanel?

Comment: Do you have SSH access?

Comment: yes i have SSH on my cPanel, but not sure how to use it lol

Comment: This looks similar to your setup: https://medium.com/laravel-power-devs/deploy-laravel-projects-on-shared-hosting-2008be6f6f03 can you check the laravel and apache log files to see what kind of error you are getting? Laravel ones should be in app/storage/logs

Comment: Yes, this is what I did exactly, and I guess mine is shared hosting

Comment: I followed someone's answer on here, it says that when ever we change the password - username - db name from .env file we need to run php artisan serve command. so as I was uploading a fresh copy zip file, i thought to change the password and username and dbname and then run the php artisan serve, and i run the command, it says **laravel deployment started: <http://127.0.0.01>** and them not sure whats it doing? does it take this much time?

Comment: `C:\xampp\htdocs\studentEnrollmentAssignment
λ php artisan serve
Laravel development server started: <http://127.0.0.1:8000>`

Comment: Have you checked laravel log or apache log for the source of error 500?